# Где найти языковой файл в WP?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на Woocommerce.

Сам Woocommerce и его Admin переведены на русский язык. В папке /wp-content/languages/woocommerce лежит файл woocommerce-ru_RU.mo Пользовательский интерфейс - 50/50 состоит из английского и русского языка. Например, остаются непереведенными фразы "Add to cart", "Adding to cart...", "Categories" и так далее.

У меня возникает подозрение, что этифразы вшиты в файлы самой темы. Смотрю в /wp-content/themes/%theme-name%/languages, там лежит файл %theme-name%.pot , в котором нет фраз "Add to cart", "Adding to cart...", "Categories". Нет их и в woocommerce-ru_RU.mo.

Коллеги, помогите, пожалуйста, одолеть этот перевод!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> помогите, пожалуйста, одолеть этот перевод!

Переводы тем должны находиться в каталоге `wp-content/languages/themes/` с расширениями `*.mo` и `*.po` и иметь название вида `twentyfifteen-ru_RU`, где
`twentyfifteen` - тестовый домен темы (texdomain. Указывается в заголовке темы и совпадает со слагом темы в [оф каталоге](https://wordpress.org/themes/)).
`ru_RU` - идентификатор языка.

Если тема из оф каталога можно переводить непосредственно в глотпрессе.   См подробнее [Как перевести тему или плагин?](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD/)

Для локального перевода тем и плагинов лучше всего использовать плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Сам WC [переведён на 100%](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/dev/ru/default/). Возможно проблема в каком-то другом плагине.

Comment: В разделе `wp-content/languages/themes/` нет языковых файлов, которые относятся к установленной теме. 
Сейчас попробую loco-translate, может быть он найдет нужный файл.

Comment: Update. Из всех перечисленных способов сработал только плагин Loco Translate.  Файлы из Poedit не подхватывались WP.

Comment: @overdd если тема из оф каталога - стоит давать ссылку. Возможно она уже частично переведена